# how to load .dll which is in different location in .exe

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll

i have implemented a simple dll project to add two numbers in visual studio 2010.i have implemented add function in a dll file and have written .def file to export the add function.
secondly, i have created another console application using visual studio 2010 which calls the add function that is created in the dll file above and in different location.
                            Issue is how to load this dll file which is in different location in to .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `LoadLibrary`

```
HMODULE hmDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("path\\to\\your\\.dll"));
```

You might have to use `GetProcAddress` to locate the functions you wish to call from your DLL.

```
typedef YourFuncReturnType (*YourFuncPtr)(FunctionArgType1, FunctionArgType2);
YourFuncPtr ptr = (YourFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hmDLL, "YourFunctionName");
YourFunctionReturnType ret = ptr(arg1, arg2);
```

And `FreeLibrary` when you're finished with it

```
FreeLibrary(hmDLL);
```

Let's say I have a DLL, and in that DLL I have a function, Foo.

DLL.cpp

```
DLLEXPORT int Foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And I have another project which I wish to access the function Foo from my DLL.

Program.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


// Define the pointer type for the function Foo
typedef int (*funcptr)(int, int);

char g_szDLLPath[] = "path\\to\\foo.dll";

int main() {
    HMODULE hmDLL = LoadLibrary(g_szDLLPath);

    if(NULL != hmDLL) {
        funcptr fooPtr = (funcptr)GetProcAddress(hmDLL, "Foo");
        if(NULL != fooPtr) {
            int result = fooPtr(5, 10);

            if(result == 15)
                    std::cout << "Yay! Foo worked as expected!" << std::endl;
                else
                    std::cout << "What the deuce! Foo returned " << result << std::endl;

                result = fooPtr(10, 10);

                if(result == 20)
                    std::cout << "Yay! Foo worked as expected!" << std::endl;
                else
                    std::cout << "What the deuce! Foo returned " << result << std::endl;
        } else {
                perror("Error Locating Foo");
                return -1;
        }
    } else {
        perror("Error Loading DLL");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct, which is why the simple solution is to put the DLL next to the EXE.